# ad blocker in Microsoft Teams webpage Tab

Tags: microsoft-teams

starting to use Microsoft Teams a lot now but I'd like to be able to use an ad blocker in a webpage tab when I add it to a Teams channel.

Is that possible?

thanks

Comment: It wasn't really a features suggestions, it was a question on how to do it.  It seems somewhat obvious to me that, if Teams uses a web browser to display a page there should be some form of control of that web browser.

Comment: Currently, this is not possible with Microsoft Teams. Please help to raise a features suggestions.